# Rotate (HTML) - DIV Cube on TouchEvent

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation

Does anyone have an idea on how I can rotate a DIV Cube on a mobile Device, like a Smartphone, by touch the screen and moving a finger?

Take a look at the following example:

```
https://codepen.io/tsluga/pen/mjMpVa
```

As you can see, I currently have an animation with the following piece of code:

```
<pre>
.cube {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation-name: myAnimation;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes myAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0,1, 0, 360deg);
    ;
  }
}
</pre>
```

How could I implement a `touchevent`? If someone presses the screen and slides over the screen/cube, I want to rotate the cube instead of the animation currently implemented.

Thanks for any Feedback

Comment: better you use some short of build-in js